# Azure Graph API get all Users in multiple groups

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a transitive way for getting all users in Azure AD groups 1 and 2?

So if *Group 3* is member of *Group 1* and user is assigned in *Group 3*, I tried the below code but it is not transitive and is not working as desired:

```
var groupmembers = _graphConnection.GetLinkedObjects(new Group(group1Guid), LinkProperty.Members, null, -1).Results.Where(x => x.ODataTypeName == oDataTypeName);
var group2members = _graphConnection.GetLinkedObjects(new Group(group2Guid), LinkProperty.Members, null, -1).Results.Where(x => x.ODataTypeName == oDataTypeName);
return groupmembers.Intersect(group2members, new GraphObjectComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you post a reference to the library you using to query Graph API?

Comment: using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient 1.0.3 just now trying to upgrade to 2.0.2 to see any newer methods and looking into the AD samples Console-GraphAPI to see any thing I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST method for achieving transitive group retrieval is documented in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn424889.aspx

The Graph Client 2.x supports transitive group retrieval as well.
HTH
V.

Comment: Hi Vibronet, is there a direct method to get users like gc.List<User>(null,filter) and add filters to check for multiple groups...or it needs to be done individually like I was trying to get all users transitive in group and then intersect. I will use the transitive method from the link. Thanks